# linux mint not booting up. is it fstab issue?

Tags: linux, linux-mint

my linux mint crashed this morning and I tried to reboot it but it keeps going into an "emergency mode" loop.
(see image bin  https://imagebin.ca/v/5gzaQbMx55rK)

i tried specifying the uuid of the home directory and also commdnting out the other drives for my plex mount but it is still throwing that same error when i boot up.

https://imagebin.ca/v/5gzbqxXycLtm

update:
i tried to boot with acpi turned off and it still threw error and loaded "emergency mode".
https://imagebin.ca/v/5h0PDJwjBOLg

Comment: After any crash particularly when system is running may corrupt file systems. If NTFS you then have to run chkdsk from Windows or fsck if ext4 from Linux depending on format of partition. You have have to repair all partitions with correct tool.

Comment: Have you tried booting with `acpi=off`?

Comment: @thanasip see update

Comment: @oldfred i ran fsck and it is still throwing that error

Comment: Did you run NTFS chkdsk? And you commented out the mount of the ESP. Did you convert to BIOS boot? And best not to mount with device like /dev/sdb5 as sdb can change & then mount will not work. My drives regularly change, if plug in a flash drive which then is sda and every other drive is one letter higher.